# Django Migration InternalError 1054 Unknown column

Tags: python, django, django-models

I added an ImageField to an existing item in models.py, I ran makeMigrations and Migrate and yet as a result now if I go to my admin panel I get the below error:

```
InternalError(1054, u"Unknown column 'activelisting.picture' in 'field list'")
```

This error goes away if I remove that ImageField.

I'm running Django==1.11.26

This is a copy of the feild:

```
picture = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='images/')
```

Very appreciative of any help on this one.

EDIT: Should have mentioned this before, but it's running on a MariaDB.

admin.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from listings.models import *

from django.contrib import admin

# Register your models here.

def make_active(modeladmin, request, queryset):
        queryset.update(active=True)
make_active.short_description = "Activate selected listings"

def make_inactive(modeladmin, request, queryset):
        queryset.update(active=False)
make_inactive.short_description = "Inactivate selected listings"

class ListingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

        #readonly_fields = ['picture']

        list_display = ('address', 'active', 'number_br', 'number_bath', 'owner', 'city',)

        list_filter = ('active', 'owner',)
        ordering = ('-active','address',)
        actions = [make_active, make_inactive,]

admin.site.register(Activelisting, ListingAdmin)

admin.site.disable_action('delete_selected')
```

models.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Activelisting(models.Model):
        active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        owner = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=True)
        address = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
        city = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
        house_types = (('house', 'House'), ('apartments', 'Apartments'), ('mobile', 'Mobile home'), ('duplex', 'Duplex'), )
        housing_type = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=house_types, default='house')
        br_types = ( (1, '1'), (2, '2'), (3, '3'), (4, '4'), (5, '5'), )
        bath_types = ( (1, '1'), (2, '2'), (3, '3'), (4, '4') )
        number_br = models.IntegerField(choices=br_types, default=1)
        number_bath = models.IntegerField(choices=bath_types, default=1)
        description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
        #picture = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='images/')

        class Meta:
                managed = False
                db_table = 'activelisting'
```

Comment: More info will be appreciated but you can try delete all 000X files in the migrations folder from your app and do `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` again, this will probably solve your problem.

Comment: no luck so far friend, I can give you a ton more info, just not sure which direction to go with the info if that makes sense since I'm not too sure what's wrong. Like it's running on Debian 10. Oh, here's a handy bit that I probably should have noted (will edit now), it's running on a MariaDB database.

Comment: Show the admin.py as well

Comment: @user3786424 show your admin.py and models.py (full) please.

Comment: Those are pretty big, lemme see if I can get you guys something that's a little more readable and yet has all the applicable elements.

Comment: alright I added a bunch more, please don't judge me too poorly, I iz learningz. :)

Comment: @GrandPhuba I commented out the parts that are causing me problems, and I cut down the massiveness that is models.py but this is the bulk of it, definitely all relevant parts (I believe).

Comment: @vcruvivenlr see above. Cheers!

Comment: @user3786424 did you tried to create manually the column into your database?

Comment: @vcruvinelr I did not, I'm not familiar enough with django to know exactly what it would expect out of the database, specifically with the fact that it's an imagefile I think it becomes a little tricky.

Comment: @user3786424 let's do things step-by-step so. You said that you're using MariaDB, right? Can you please go to your settings.py, put a sqlite3 database (as original) and do makemigrations and migrate again? Tell me if you get any error.

Comment: @vcruvinelr now I'm getting errors like "original_exception 
OperationalError('no such table: activelisting',)", I ran makemigrations and migrate a couple times to see if it would auto generate the tables. I also commented out the meta section which defined the db_table =. It's weird, I might create myself a new app from the ground up and see if I see any of these kinds of errors. This app was ultimately migrated from another server with an existing db.

Comment: This model run smoothly with sqlite3 here. This error appears in the MariaDB or SQLite as I suggested?

Comment: Expanding on this a little bit, it appears to be when I add anything to the an existing model. I am researching this more. But to answer your question the error I got was when I switched to sqlite3 to troubleshoot per your request.

Comment: Ok, the issue is that the database was existing and Managed was originally set to False. I can change this to true and if I drop the existing table this resolves the issue, but I'd rather have django somehow integrate with the existing table, and then start adding data as needed (rather than me manually adding the fields to SQL).